# Force <td> to respect new width, or ignore previous width

Tags: html, css

I am working on cleaning up my companies newsletter emails. My issue is that I would like to force my `<td>` to respect the width that I specify rather than following the widths of the previous `<td>`. The other issue is that this needs to be very email client compatible.

Here's a jsfiddle of what I'm working on. http://jsfiddle.net/zwf0dL8r/ Sorry about the inline styles, aren't html emails great..

As you can see, the light grey areas are following the width of the first `<td>` which is holding the cpap.com logo.

Ideally, I wanted to be able to define the widths of `<td>`s to something new, each time I create a new `<tbody>`..

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  I think you'll have to be a bit more specific about what you're trying to do and maybe explain what you've tried already before any useful help can be offered.

Comment: Try to explain more by showing your code (what ever you have created so far) and create a demo of your code using jsfiddle.net and share! That will be more helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS to force some behavior, but the browser or email client generally calculate the width of columns automatically based on content, using the widest specified width for the column when the content is shorter. To avoid this you can add the property `table-layout: fixed;` to the style of the table, but you will have to manually assign the correct widths for each column.

Tables with fixed layout are faster to display but don't resize according to content. The larger content overflows it's cell, causing an ugly looking overlapping data.

Take a look here for e-mail client compatibility: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

---

**Edit.:**

To make the bellow cell take the space of the above cells you can add a `colspan="numOfColsToTake"`.

What many people forget is that each `<TD>` define a column, not only an individual cell. Imagine you are designing it on Excel. If you would do this on Excel, you would have to use the `merge cells` option for the bellow cell to take the space of the 2 above. The `colspan` attribute of `<TD>` elements makes exactly this.

```
<td colspan="2"><p>Something</p></td>
```

Comment: I did define `table-layout:fixed` on my table tag. But it doesn't seem to help the issue. The previous employee, or who ever designed this email structure that we use seemed extremely sloppy redundant. The "fix" that they used for just about everything was to create a new table for each "chunk" of the newsletter/email. My thinking was there should be no reason to use more than 1 table and break that up with tbody's.

Comment: This is CSS so you have to define it on the `style` attribute this way: `style="table-layout: fixed;"`.
Using more than one table was a common practice back then when tableless was still a legend. This makes the structure of a cell be independent of the rest. Say if you have a cell that may be divided in 2 columns and the cell bellow it must be divided in 5. You would have to play with colspans ans rowspans to get it right and the use of the famous "spacer.gif" (a transparent 1px gif) for column aligning. With a nested table, it's a no brainer.

Comment: I guess I should have clarified, I have defined `table-layout: fixed` in the STYLE of my table tag, and the `<td>s` within my first table row are correctly sized based on the content, but I still cant explicitly define the width of subsequent `<td>` tags.

Comment: If this td's are from nested tables you will have to set this on every one of these. All tables nested will have to be fixed for you to get absolute control over the widths.

Comment: I am only using 1 table. Thats what I am trying to accomplish. Is this not possible?

Comment: No, it isn't. If your cell count and widths change per row you will have to play with `colspan` attributes on the `td` elements or use nested tables.

Comment: hmm, ok makes sense, I was hoping I could just nest `<tbody>s` under one main `<table>`. I'll just go with nested `<tables>`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, see my edit about colspans. If your structure is simple, it may be all you need.